# Cheerio: How to get all tags under a grandparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I would like to grab all `img` tags under an arbitrary level of nested siblings from a specified parent tag but my implementation isn't printing out any `el`.

```
<div class='grand'>
    <div>
        <img src='1.png'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src='2.png'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src='3.png'>
</div>
```

My implementation so far:

```
let images = $('div.grand').siblings().find('img')
images.each((i, el) => {
    console.log($(el).html()) //prints empty string
})
```

Essentially, I would like to obtain the same result as the `soup.findAll('img')` of `BeautifulSoup` in python.

Comment: `$('div.grand > div > img')` - will work for selecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't print out the empty string - it doesn't print *anything* in the `each`, because no elements are matched.

To find elements matching a selector which are a descendant of elements matching another selector, put a space between them. Here, for `img`s which descent from `.grand`, you'd use `.grand img`:

```
$('.grand img').each((i, el) => {
    console.log(el.attribs.src)
});
```

Result:

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
```

Comment: `el.attribs.src`  ??? I think you have got a typo. I don't think there is such a thing called `attribs`

Comment: It's not a typo, the code works fine - feel free to install Cheerio and see for yourself. Remember, this is in Node - the `el` is not an HTMLElement, but a Cheerio element.

Answer (score 0):

You were close! To perform what you need:

```
$(".grand img").each(function() {
  const src = $(this).attr("src")
  console.log(src)
})
```

This takes advantage of `$(this)` to access the `src` attribute of the referenced object

`.grand img` means access ALL children inside the elements with a class of `grand`